# Android - script on device

Tags: android, intune

We have some android devices, that are enrolled with Intune. And automatically some APK is installed from intune - which work fine.

However, additional, there must be placed a config.json on the desktop (the apk use that). I am looking for a way this to automatically happen.

Is there a way to build this config.json file into the APK and it then during install then copy automatically to the desktop ?

Or some other way to "script" this.

Hope someone has some good idea, as the last way is to manually with a file explorer on the device, to save the file on the desktop, which is not the optimal way

Looking for feedback

Comment: "there must be placed a config.json on the desktop" -- Android does not have a desktop. Please explain, **in detail**, what you consider to be the "desktop". "Is there a way to build this config.json file into the APK and it then during install then copy automatically to the desktop ?" -- no. Not only does Android not have a desktop, but you cannot modify somebody's APK this way, and there is no way for an APK to automatically copy a file on installation.

Comment: yes ok - when I say "desktop" I mean the main screen you see when you startup the device, where you see the apps installed etc

Comment: That is not a directory where you place files. Please explain, **in detail**, why you think a `config.json` file goes where you think a "desktop" is.